# Draw a Signal strength indicator

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given the signal level `L` in the range `0-4`. Your program should draw the following ASCII art.

When `L=0`:

```
               ....
               ....
          .... ....
          .... ....
     .... .... ....
     .... .... ....
.... .... .... ....
.... .... .... ....
.... .... .... ....
```

When `L=1`:

```
               ....
               ....
          .... ....
          .... ....
     .... .... ....
     .... .... ....
oooo .... .... ....
oooo .... .... ....
oooo .... .... ....
```

When `L=2`:

```
               ....
               ....
          .... ....
          .... ....
     oooo .... ....
     oooo .... ....
oooo oooo .... ....
oooo oooo .... ....
oooo oooo .... ....
```

And etc. You can change the characters `o` and `.` to others, it's up to you. Trailing spaces are allowed.

This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: That would include allowing trailing spaces on each line, correct?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Yes, it is would be correct.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>47</sup> 46 bytes

```
' .o'{~[:|.@|:[:,/(4,&0@#"+3+2*i.4)#"+1+4{.$&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldDBCsIwDAbg@57ip461XWu2bt3BgiAKnsSD1x3FoV72AB179VqEgogoBgKB8CUk98CID1g7cGjUcDGXhN3psA8cNHI/926izeR6pythdVFvFky1qilvZGUsjbKe8sIEmR23hBcUBVUi9WUpOk1zkp5WsLlx7@i5Sei60DLafLaaEinTqI9GV50n1vxpvl2EDL8ju5yvIwam4uMMGrSw4QE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 17 bytes

```
4ɾ≥vS4ɾd›*¶+4*⁋↵§
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI0yb7iiaV2UzTJvmTigLoqwrYrNCrigYvihrXCpyIsIiIsIjMiXQ==)

-3 thanks to Seggan.

```
4ɾ≥               # Create a map of ones and zeroes corresponding to the bar characters.
   vS             # Stringify those
     4ɾd›         # Create the range [3, 5, 7, 9]
         *        # And repeat each char of those
          ¶+      # Append a newline to each
            4*    # Repeat each four times
              ⁋↵  # Turn into a list of lines
                § # Rotate 90°
```

Comment: Vyxal doesn't have something to repeat an integer as string? The challenge allows other characters, so no need for the `‛.o$İ` if you can interpret the `0`/`1` as strings so the `*` repeats it instead of multiply. I see there is also `ẋ` to repeat, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: [17 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI0yb7iiaV2UzTJvmTigLoqwrYrNCrigYvihrXCpyIsIiIsIjMiXQ==) @KevinCruijssen yeah, `vS` works

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 76 bytes

```python
f=lambda L,i=0:i<36and". o"[i%4+i/8<3or-(i%4<L)]*4+" \n"[i%4>2]+f(L,i+1)or""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctNCsIwEEDhqwwDwozxP1WkpJ6gN9AuIjU60E7K0I2nj8Xl4@NN3/mT1ZeSmiGOzz5Cu5HmUEvwl6g97iDjXVaVk/01@GxbWiK03K0rh/DQP95OnUu0jO7I2RBLygYComBR3y86cw2Tic6USJjLDw)

-2 bytes by [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 91 bytes

```python
f=lambda L:L<45and" ".join(4*" o."[j+j+L//5>5and~(j<L%5)]for j in[0,1,2,3])+"\n"+f(L+5)or""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBDoIwEADAr2w2Mdm1DajQC0Fe0B8ghxqsttEtabh44etVzjPLd30laUrx17f73GcHtrN9a5zMCFjFFITaI0KqcIwqKlvXZth1o9jbg@HJpwwRgownfdYX3Uys8CaoPFllOGXEspfwL5CdPB9kuIMlB1nJU2AuPw)

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##HctRCsIwDIDhq4SA0KwqulWR0XmC3UD3UJmdAU1G2Iunr8PHn49//i4vlaaU3L3T5zEm6LfcHVqOzTnJiHtQvPEmVBfPsQ5qO7dW7Gmogke4y1@v9eCzW09/JDXEktWAgQUsyfR0J2phNpbFZcdE5Qc)

Comment: @dingledooper Good idea. But it could be shorter by changing to `/8` instead of `*8`.

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 48 bytes

Prompts for n

```
⊖⍉⊃((n↑m)⍴¨⊂⊂4⍴'0'),((-4-n←⎕)↑m←1+2×⍳4)⍴¨⊂⊂4⍴','
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3t/6OuaY96Ox91NWto5D1qm5ir@ah3y6EVj7qagMgEyFY3UNfU0dDQNdEFSk8AatYEqQLp1zY6PP1R72YTDB066v@BRnP9T@My4FJXUOdK4zKE0kZQ2hhKm3ABAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 75 bytes

```
def f(n,j=4):print(*(" .o"[(i>=j)*~(n<i)]*4for i in b""));1/j;f(n,j-.5)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3vVNS0xTSNPJ0smxNNK0KijLzSjS0NJQU9PKVojUy7WyzNLXqNPJsMjVjtUzS8osUMhUy8xSSlBiZmFmUNDWtDfWzrMG6dfVMNaFG6oDU5YHUFSXmpadqmGpacSmUFFVaARVqcimkViSnFpRArYLqgTkHAA)

Finishes with an exception. The `b""` string contains the literal bytes `0x01` `0x02` `0x03` `0x04`, but they're invisible here.

Could probably be improved with some more tweaking.

### 76 bytes

```
def f(n,j=4):print(*(" .o"[(i>=j)*~(n<i)]*4for i in b""));j>0!=f(n,j-.5)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3fVJS0xTSNPJ0smxNNK0KijLzSjS0NJQU9PKVojUy7WyzNLXqNPJsMjVjtUzS8osUMhUy8xSSlBiZmFmUNDWts-wMFG3B2nX1TDUhZu4DqcsDqStKzEtP1TDVtAKq0LSGGA5VBHMAAA)

No error.

Comment: Ok how do you know when to use lambda or when to use regular function? Also what is that `b"..."` string doing

Comment: In this case the function doesn't return anything, it prints to stdout, so it's shorter to use `def`. Here the `b""` string acts as equivalent to `[1,2,3,4]`, but it's shorter: see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51622).

Comment: @Neil I'm not sure whether you're joking, but in either case "substandard" doesn't come across very nice. Also, ATO and TIO both generate markdown which renders as those 4 literal bytes, but they're invisible in both cases (I was wrong; it's not SE markdown's fault), so I changed it to the clearer `\1\2\3\4`. You're welcome to submit constructive feedback on the GitHub repository: https://github.com/attempt-this-online/attempt-this-online

Comment: Thanks for correcting your post.

Comment: I checked my poor shoddy inferior imperfect inadequate second-rate unacceptable thesaurus but it didn't come up with a better synonym. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
↑Ｅ⁴Ｅ⁴×§.o›Ｉθι⁺³⊗ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMqtEBHwTexQMMEToVk5qYWaziWeOalpFZoKOnlK@kouBelJpakFmk4JxaXaBRq6ihkagKJgJzSYg1jHQWX/NKknNQUDaAgCFj//2/0X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  ⁴                 Literal integer `4`
 Ｅ                  Map over implicit range
    ⁴               Literal integer `4`
   Ｅ                Map over implicit range
       .o           Literal string `.o`
      §             Indexed by
           θ        Input `L`
          Ｉ         Cast to integer
         ›          Is greater than
            ι       Outer value
     ×              Repeated by
              ³     Literal integer `3`
             ⁺      Plus
                ι   Outer value
               ⊗    Doubled
↑                   Print rotated 90° anticlockwise
```

Charcoal prints each array element in its own row (or column, if rotated as it is here) and automatically double-spaces nested arrays when printing them.

14 bytes by using the custom characters `1` and `0` instead of `o` and `.`:

```
↑Ｅ⁴Ｅ⁴⭆⁺³⊗ι›Ｉθι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMqtEBHwTexQMMETgWXAGXSQZyAnNJiDWMdBZf80qSc1BSNTE1NHQX3otTEktQiDefE4hKNQqAAUBQIrP//N/qvW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  ⁴             Literal integer `4`
 Ｅ              Map over implicit range
    ⁴           Literal integer `4`
   Ｅ            Map over implicit range
        ³       Literal integer `3`
       ⁺        Plus
          ι     Outer value
         ⊗      Doubled
     ⭆          Map over implicit range and join
            θ   Input `L`
           Ｉ    Cast to integer
          ›     Is greater than
             ι  Outer value
↑               Print rotated 90° anticlockwise
```

Comment: The challenge allows other characters than `.o`, so you can simply use the `01` for [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMqtEBHwTexQMMEToVk5qYWazgnFpdouBelJpakFkE4hZo6CpmaQCIgp7RYw1hHwSW/NCknNUUDKAgC1v//G/3XLcsBAA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I guess I could add a 14 byte alternative to show how it should be done using `0` and `1`...

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I've posted that 14 byte alternative now.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 73 bytes

```javascript
L=>(g=i=>i--?` . 
 o`[i%20?i%5&&i/20+2*(x=i/5&3)<9|x+L&4:3]+g(i):'')(180)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDoIwEADAu6/YC6W1KdQCiQILH@AHxgSCtFlDqAFjOPj3ymlO8xq@wzau9P6oxT@nYDF02HCHhA0p1faQwAl8f6fI6JaigjFKjZbmzHektGCZqG@/XXYsL7OHdJxEGceCX65aBOtX4AQIugKCGiE/lFLA6JfNz1Mye8ftUUQV/g)

-1 byte by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 90 bytes

```javascript
L=>(g=i=>i>8?'':[1,2,3,4].map(j=>' o.'[j+j+i<8?0:j>L?2:1].repeat(4)).join` `+`
`+g(++i))``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoMwEADAe1@xt2xYG9R6KGriB/yBCAk2ygZrRKXfTz3NZYL7uXM6eL@eW/z4NOvUa4OLZm3YvDsh6qHIyuyVVaP6uh2DNgKiEkOgQNy@u7wOpu/KuhjV4XfvLqykVCHyZsGSfVhakIiltDbN8QBk0JA3wNBqqG6JJExxO@Pq1RoXnPHOTfoD)

Comment: I was just about to post my own js answer and you beat it by half

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Don't worry about posting not so well-golfed code. Idea behind could still be interesting somehow.

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##DctBDoIwEADAu6/YC6W1KdQCiQILH@AHxgSCtFlDqAFjOPj3ymlO8xq@wzau9P6oxT@nYDF02HCHhA0p1faQwAl8f6fI6JaigjFKjZbmzHektGCZqG@/XXYsL7OHdJxEGceCX65aBOtX4AQIugKCGiE/lFLA6JfNz1Mye8ftUUQV/g)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>104</s> <s>100</s> 93 bytes

```python
lambda n:[f'{"oooo "*(b:=n-4+(k:=min(i,7)//2+1))+".... "*(k-max(0,b)):>20}'for i in range(9)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpBDsIgEAC/Qrh0t6W2Vo1Kgh9RDxBFSWUhpAeN8e1IvTi3mUx8TfdAq11M2apTfmhvLpqRPNrqzUOB8RqMVNSuGxil8o7AiS123dAsERu@KMzP2Hr9hF4YRHkY@k9lQ2KOOWJJ0@0KezznOdE/bVDG5GgCQlF7HeFnwhbH/AU)

Returns a list of strings, allowed [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/17095#17095).

Thanks everyone for all the tips on my previous python answer. I used some of those tips here!

Comment: @DialFrost yeah, i don't even know how tsh's answer even works. recursion is way out of my league :P

Comment: tsh's answer builds the 36 parts individually.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, 99 bytes

```
x=>"0004003402341234"[r="replace"](/\d{4}/g,"$&\n$&\n")[r](/\d/g,y=>+y?x<y?".... ":"oooo ":"     ")
```

(Didn't it use to be `$0` for this and not `$&`?)

Comment: The `+` is unnecessary for -1 byte

Comment: @tsh fixed, I think

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
4L‹ā·>×ε4иø}ζR€.B»
```

Uses `01` instead of `o.` respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v8wNWFiMWX//zRM4oC5xIHCtz7Dl861NNC4w7h9zrZS4oKsLkLCu///Mg) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9ybJKSZ15BaYmVgpK9nw6Xkn9pCYSn4/ffxOdRw84jjYe22x2efm6ryYUdh3fUntsW9KhpjZ7Tod3/dQ5ts/8PAA).

**Explanation:**

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E because it can zip/transpose on a list of strings, where the new version would require a character-matrix.

```python
4L      # Push list [1,2,3,4]
  ‹     # Check for each whether it's larger than the (implicit) input
   ā    # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping): [1,2,3,4]
    ·   # Double each: [2,4,6,8]
     >  # Increase each by 1: [3,5,7,9]
      × # Repeat the earlier checks that many times as strings
        #  (e.g. input=2 → [0,0,1,1] → ["000","00000","1111111","111111111"])
ε       # Map over each string:
 4и     #  Repeat it 4 times as list
   ø    #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
}ζ      # After the map: zip/transpose again, with implicit " " as filler
  R     # Reverse this list of lists
   €    # Map over each inner list:
    .B  #  Box: expand the single filler space to length 4 by adding trailing
        #  spaces based on the string with the longest length in the list
      » # Join each inner list by spaces; and then each string by newlines
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 65 bytes

```ruby
->n{(0..8).map{|x|(0..3).map{|y|(y<3-x/2?" ":y<n ??o:?.)*3}*' '}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNAT89CUy83saC6pqIGxDOG8iprNCptjHUr9I3slRSUrCpt8hTs7fOt7PU0tYxrtdQV1Gtr/xeUlhQrpEUbxf4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

Uses `1/0` instead of `o/.`.

```apl
3 5 7 9,.{¯9 5↑⍺4⍴⍕⍵}4↑⍴∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///31jBVMFcwVJHr/rQeksF00dtEx/17jJ51LvlUe/UR71ba03AIlsedcww/J/2qG3Co96@R31TPf0fdTUfWm8MkuybGhzkDCRDPDyD/0Pk2iYYcFUDmSD1Xc1pQHMedbdA@OrqtYdWPOrdbAoA)

`⍴∘1`: Reshape of 1. Creates a vector of `L` 1's.
`4↑`: Take 4. Extend to length 4 by appending 0's.

`,.{...}`: Inner product. Pair elements from the computed boolean vector and `3 5 7 9` and call the inner dfn on it. Reduce the resulting list by concatenating character matrices horizontally.
`⍕⍵`: Format. Convert the 1 or 0 to a string.
`⍺4⍴`: Reshape into a `⍺×4` character matrix by replicating the digit.
`¯9 5↑`: Extend to a `9×5` matrix by padding with spaces to the top and right.

Comment: Can you add a quick explanation?  I understand most of it but not all and want to see if I can steal any ideas to improve my J answer.

Comment: @Jonah Added a bit of text. *Reshape* and *Overtake* do most of the work here, the inner product combines a reduction (`,/`) and `¨` to save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 78 bytes

```c
j,i;f(x){for(i=180;--i;putchar(j?i%5&&i/35+j/5<5?j/5+x>3?79:46:32:10))j=i%20;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3LCoMwEEX3@QoRlAlpMGrTR0brj3QjAdsJNC3WgiD59jRuDpezuMfKh7UxugPhBCvfpvcM1NcXhVISfn6LfY4zuIEKXZZUtVq4Snd6SBTrrR3OV3M8mbYxteLc9VQ0CkMkv2SvkTzwjaXHDHZBvULqNApBuwbiyFLgC/nd52kHFuIf)

Pretty straightforward approach:
often times in C is convenient to iterate backwards the entire volume so we start with *i=lines x width*.
Each time we print the proper character based on div modulus values.

Luckily I found that I could save some Bytes by using i%35 instead of i%40 which would require some extra operations to fit the right shape of each bar.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
4RðḤ‘ṁ"@>z⁶Ṛx4Y
```

Prints with `o` as `0` and `.` as `1`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//NFLDsOG4pOKAmOG5gSJAPnrigbbhuZp4NFn///8x)**

#### How?

```
4RðḤ‘x"@>z⁶Ṛx4Y - Main Link: integer, L
4               - four
 R              - range -> [1,2,3,4]
  ð             - new dyadic chain - f(X=[1,2,3,4], L)
   Ḥ            - double X          -> [2,4,6,8]
    ‘           - increment         -> [3,5,7,9]
        >       - X greater than L? -> [1>L,2>L,3>L,4>L]
       @        - with swapped arguments - f([1>L,2>L,3>L,4>L], [3,5,7,9]):
      "         -   zip with:
     x          -     times -> [[1>L,1>L,1>L],[2>L,2>L,2>L,2>L,2>L],[3>L,...],[4>L...]]
         z⁶     - transpose with filler of space characters
           Ṛ    - reverse
            x4  - times four (vectorises)
              Y - join with newline characters
                - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 76 bytes

```python
lambda n:"".join(". o"[i<~i%4*8or-(i%4<n)]*4+"   \n"[i%4]for i in range(36))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XclBCsIwEEbhq/wMFCYtdtMoUtKT2C4iGh2xMyV048arx6zdPd63ffan6VDSNJd3XK@3CB2J@peJMvUwukj4SuPbs@UD1wjqltZ3BGDWqo1fkmUIRJGjPu48nJwrf@/oRmxZdOfEUvkH)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 11, <s>105</s> 102 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=36;i-->0;)System.out.print((i/4>8-i%4*2?" ":n<i%4?".":"o").repeat(4)+(i%4<1?"\n":" "));}
```

Could probably be golfed slightly more by removing the `.repeat(4)` and looping `144` times instead, but I don't have the time to figure it out for now.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZBPS8QwEMXv@ymGASGxJK5aRJr@OXtwPexRPcRuVrJ2p6VNF2TpZ6@z3aIg6GVI3nvh/TI7e7Bqt/kYy8p2HTxaT8cFgKfg2q0tHaxOV4BD7TdQCtaBpGFpWPDogg2@hBUQZDCSyo/bup1CPru9M16pfGnk@rMLbq/rPuimZVMIfxXn98pfxJc3BQImlPK5QI0J1ih16xpng4hlJFhPrwt8IbYApTTDaE7NTf9WcfMMMNHtmV2sAze8P79aeeb@4Vka8GkW84yi2QT4jVaRwAdq@pAARn766F@xpz6cc98p0ryg/97M3jCtbxi/AA)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                   // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=36;i-->0;) //  Loop `i` in the range (36,0]:
    System.out.print(  //   Print:
       (i/4            //    If `i` integer-divided by 4
        >              //    is larger than
        8-i%4*2?       //    8 minus `i` modulo-4 times 2
         " "           //     Use a space
        :n<i%4?        //    Else-if the input is smaller than `i` modulo-4:
         "."           //     Use a dot
        :              //    Else:
         "o"           //     Use an O
       ).repeat(4)     //    Repeat this character 4 times
       +(i%4<1?        //    Once every four iterations:
         "\n"          //     Append a newline
        :              //    Every other iteration:
         " "));        //     Append a space instead
```

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 544 bytes

```
+[-->---[-<]>]>[<<+>>>+<-]<-[>--<-------]>+[<+>-]>[<+>-]+++++++[<++>-]>+++++[<++>-]>-[>+<-----]>---<,>[<->-]<[>>+<<-[>>>>+<<<<-[>>>>>>+<<<<<<-[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]]]]++[<+++++[<<<<...>>>>-]>->>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<<<....[>]<.>>]++[<+++++[<<<<..>>>>-]>->>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<....[<]>.[>]>>>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<<<....[>]<.>>]++[<<<<<.....>>>>>->>>>[<]<<<<<<<....[<]>.[>]>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<....[<]>.[>]>>>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<<<....[>]<.>>]+++[->>[<]<<<<<....[<]>.[>]>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<....[<]>.[>]>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<....[<]>.[>]>>>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<<<....[>]<.>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZHBCgIxDEQ/KKYXr0N@JOSggiCCB8Hvr5N2a13WgyDOYbdJ583A7vF@uNzOj9O1VnFVU1VXhIU5IGYm0IA6L6BdYeK80rTkS7o4tOVqIChYKD6wI8OSgGdy5rYKjOMyzPG14CqoHt0aqFJKWjJ82B2BKRqKW4C2Dbom37lG8SMkat8Fj11L7ZkT@JD3Ux3/1DRs6H/11rp/Ag)

Builds each line in segments. Ungolfed:

```
memory layout
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13
' '  dot  'o'  \n   cnt  inp  0    Nge1 0    Nge2 0    Nge3 0    Nge4

constants
space = 32
+[-->---[-<]>]>
[<<+>>>+<-]<
o = 111
-[>--<-------]>+
[<+>-]
dot = 46
>[<+>-]
+++++++[<++>-]
\n = 10
>+++++[<++>-]>
get input
-[>+<-----]>---<,>[<->-]<#

check 0
[
  >>+<<
  check 1
  -[
    >>>>+<<<<
    check 2
    -[
     >>>>>>+<<<<<<
     check 3
      -[
        >>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<
        check 4
        -
      ]
    ]
  ]
]#
first 2 lines
++[
  15 spaces
  <+++++[<<<<...>>>>-]>-
  4 bar segment
  >>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<<<....
  [>]<.>>
]
next 2 lines
++[
  10 spaces
  <+++++[<<<<..>>>>-]>-
  3 bar segment
  >>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<....
  space
  [<]>.[>]>
  4 bar segment
  >>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<<<....
  [>]<.>>
]
next 2 lines
++[
  5 spaces
  <<<<<.....>>>>>-
  2 bar segment
  >>>>[<]<<<<<<<....
  space
  [<]>.[>]>
  3 bar segment
  >>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<....
  space
  [<]>.[>]>
  4 bar segment
  >>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<<<....
  [>]<.>>
]
last 3 lines
+++[
  -
  1 bar segment
  >>[<]<<<<<....
  space
  [<]>.[>]>
  2 bar segment
  >>>>[<]<<<<<<<....
  space
  [<]>.[>]>
  3 bar segment
  >>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<....
  space
  [<]>.[>]>
  4 bar segment
  >>>>>>>>[<]<<<<<<<<<<<....
  [>]<.>>
]
```

It could probably be shorter with a complex loop to handle generating each line but I couldn't get something like that to work.